# Problem to update fcurve driver

Tags: python, drivers

My problem is get the "angle" for updating the expression inside , in this example the expression is a simple string for explain , but i want controll expression by floatprop(that is not a problem) problem is how to get.

```
import bpy

def update_the_driver():
    ###this funcition is because driver expression is controlling by some variable
    ob = bpy.context.object

    bend = ob.modifiers.get("bend")
    fcurve = getattr(bend, "angle")####Problem
    driver = fcurve.driver####problem

    driver.expression = "sin(frame/20)"###problem

    return

def make_driver():
    ###this is because i call by a boolean on

    ###some check for presence about modifier name
    #if my_bool is True:
        ob = bpy.context.object
        bend = ob.modifiers.new(name="bend", type='SIMPLE_DEFORM')
        bend.deform_method = 'BEND'

        bend.driver_add("angle")

        update_the_driver()
    #if my_bool is False:

        ###delete diver, and modifier.

    return

make_driver()

#####some controller to call make_driver and update the drivers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To get the driver**

Py console code. Look at the drivers collection in the animation data. (animation data can be `None` need to test)

Default file with cube selected and active. Cube has a deform modifier `mod`  name "SimpleDeform".  The "angle" property of the modifier has driver.  One component of the cubes location has a driver.

```
>>> ob = C.object
>>> for fcurve in ob.animation_data.drivers:
...     fcurve.data_path
...     
'location'
'modifiers["SimpleDeform"].angle'
```

Just as we added the driver to the modifier, we can get the path from the `ID` object (in this case `bpy.types.Object` type context object)

```
>>> mod =  C.object.modifiers['SimpleDeform']

>>> mod.id_data
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> mod.id_data is C.object
True

>>> mod.path_from_id("angle")
'modifiers["SimpleDeform"].angle'
```

This is our "key" to finding driver

```
>>> key = 'modifiers["SimpleDeform"].angle'
>>> fcurve = C.object.animation_data.drivers.find(key)
>>> fcurve
bpy.data.objects['Cube']...FCurve

>>> fcurve.driver.expression
'var + 0.785'

>>> key = "badkey"
>>> C.object.animation_data.drivers.find(key) is None
True
```

Here is a helper method, pass an object which returns the angle property driver of a deform modifier named `modname` or `None`

```
def get_deform_angle_driver(ob, modname):
    # does ob have modifiers
    if not hasattr(ob, "modifiers"):
        return None
    # does ob have animation data
    ad = ob.animation_data
    if not ad:
        return None
    # does ob have a modifier of that name
    bend = ob.modifiers.get(modname)
    if not bend:
        return None
    # make the key
    key = bend.path_from_id("angle")
    #key = 'modifiers["%s"].angle' % modname
    fcurve = ad.drivers.find(key)
    # is there a driver fcurve?
    if not fcurve:
        return None
    # woo hoo.. return the drive fcurve
    driver = fcurve.driver

    #driver.expression = "sin(frame/20)"

    return fcurve

# test code
import bpy
ob = bpy.context.object
fcurve = get_deform_angle_driver(ob, "bend")
print(fcurve)
```

Comment: Sorry bat , im confused at this round,  if i use : fcurve = bpy.context.object.animation_data.drivers.find(key)
give me error, is that the way to find custom named modifier? just for not get another modifier with same "Simpledeform"... I'm not very good on the console

Comment: `key = 'modifiers["%s"].angle'` % mod.name`  So if your modifier `mod` has name "bend" the key is `'modifiers["bend"].angle'`

Comment: fcurve = bpy.context.object.animation_data.drivers.find(key) print(fcurve) ... None... not undertand why the name is exactly

Comment: Sorry bat, undertand my problem in the first time i put "modifiers['bend'].angle"  (
quotation marks error) now work !